# Deriving Kelly's criterion for betting

Tags: probability

I have read [this reference](http://www.dummies.com/personal-finance/investing/investing-strategies/kelly-criterion-method-of-money-management/) and it gives a proof of Kelly's formula in probability, the thing is that I want to do it with out using Calculus. What I have tried so far is the following:

> **Attempt**

I divided in steps;

1) When we are at time $t=0$ we have our money, so for simplicity we assume it is $1$.

2) Now when we are at time $t=1$, we bet our quantity, denoted by $f$, we are searching the optimum $f$, so then,if we win we will have $bf$ with probability $p$, where $b$ is what we could win if we win, so we will loose $f$ with probability $1-p=q$, then what we gain is $$G_1=pbf-fq$$

3) The next time we will bet $fG_1$ so we have that we win $b(pb-q)f^2$ with probability $p$ and we will loose $(pb-q)f^2$ with probability $q$ so that we gain is

$$G_2=p(b(pb-q)f^2)-q((pb-q)f^2)$$

4) Doing this in general we will have the recurrence formula,

$$G_n=pbfG_{n-1}-qfG_{n-1}$$

Then moving some things we get,

$$G_n=pbfG_{n-1}-qfG_{n-1}=fG_{n-1}(pb-(1-p))=fG_{n-1}(p(b+1)-1)$$

But then to get the alternative formula given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion) I have to get that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{G_{n}}{G_{n-1}}=f^2 b$$

The thing is that I think there is no reason why I should get that result. So Am I on the right track? if yes How can I get this last step so that the result follows? or how can I fix my argument, if it is wrong.

> **Edition**

I can think the above part as maximizing the sum average,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{G_0+G_1+\ldots G_n}{n}$$

and by the above recursion formula we get

$$G_n=(pbf)^n+(qf)^n$$

Then,

$$G_0+G_1+\ldots G_n= \sum_{k=1}^{n}(pbf)^k+(qf)^k$$

But the thing is that I don't know how to proceed after this.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: After step (2) your expected gain is $G_1$, then your expected bankroll is $E[b_1] = b+G_1$ and your actual bankroll would be either $b_1 = b(1+f)$ or $b_1 = b(1 - f)$. Why in  step (3) would you bet $fG_1$?

Comment: Because I am betting all I've got

Comment: Can you elaborate more please ?

Comment: What you've got after one step is $b(1 \pm f)$, and $G_1$ is not all you've got.

Comment: So is everything wrong ?

Comment: You missed the probability in your first comment ;)

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin What can be done?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. This scenario like many others in probability is mainly about modeling, and calculus is just one of the tools along the way but not one of its defining characteristics. Are you trying to model the situation differently or what? Like many probability problems this one is inherently discrete, we know exactly what it is in the short run, and asymptotic analysis sheds more light on it for the long run. You won't gain any more insight by devising a way to do the math differently.

Comment: Yes I want to do it without calculus :), so I thought this way, I read Wikipedia proof and some sort of that but I don't know how to proceed with this idea That I've got :)

Comment: Am I clear now ?

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I've edited my post :)